# Testing Django API on a VPS with curl

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework, vps, debian-stretch

I'm trying to access on my Django API using curl from my local terminal to a VSP

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json; indent=4' -u admin:password http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/
```

So, I tried many things like,

- replace `admin:password` to my actual vps `root@password`
- replace `admin:password` to my actual database `admin@password`
- replace `http://127.0.0.1:8000` to my vps url
- replace the port `8000` by `22`, or `80`, `8080`

And by the way, I don't know is I have to change `/users/` by `/root/` or anything else.

I have tried many mix and nothing works.
Here what I'm testing : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#testing-our-api

If important, my vps machine is Debian 9 (Stretch)

Think you for your help

Comment: You going to have to setup cors.

Comment: You could use the token. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`curl -H 'Accept: applicatin/json; indent=4' -u [superuser username]:[superuser password] http://YOURVPSIPADDRESS/users/`

The `admin:password` should be the superuser username and password on your Django site not the username or password for your database or VPS. Ensure a superuser has been created for your Django site on your VPS.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I got this message : 
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

I had this message before, and searching it on Google, but still don't get if it's vps setting to do or if I had to correct my curl syntax

Comment: Did you try making sure connections to port 80 are being accepted on your VPS? What cloud server are you using?

Comment: Inded, my VPS had no firewall, so I activated it, and allowed port 80 (TCP protocole).
Now I got this message : curl: (7) Failed to connect to [ip address] port 80: Connection refused